# Dual citizen leaving Australia on a German passport

Tags: passport, dual-citizenship

I've found a number of similar questions. However none of them are an exact match, hence I need to ask this.

I just found out that my grandmother in Germany has passed away and I would need to travel this Saturday (today is Tuesday AEDT). Unfortunately, my Australian passport expired May 2017. I am aware that the Passport Office has priority service, however as the passport number changes and you normally need the number to book in the flight, I won't be able to book the flight in time.

I am a German dual citizen and have a valid German passport. I am wondering if I can leave Australia with my German passport? I know themat once I am in Germany, I can go to the Consulate Office and apply for a 6-month emergency passport, so I'm not concerned about coming back. But it's more whether Australian immigration will let me leave.

Comment: You can book the flight with your German passport and then use your Australian passport when you actually travel.  I do that all the time in the US, anyway.  In most cases it's not mandatory to provide any passport information at all when you book the flight; it's only needed when you check in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spoke to the Department of Home Affairs regarding my situation and they advised that I can leave Australia with the German passport, however at the passport counter they will be using the expired Australian passport as an 'Immigration Reference' to prove that I am an Australian citizen.

Answer (score 5):

You can not leave on your German passport, because you did not enter on your German passport. As an Australian citizen, you need to use your Australian passport to leave, but will use your German passport to enter Germany.

This means that you use your ***German*** passport to book your flight, and you get your new Australian passport in time to leave Australia. You will later leave Germany on your German passport, and enter Australia on your (new) Australian passport.